# Can you show a list (ex calendar) from a subsite to the parent site in Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have several departmental subsites that have calendars, or announcement webparts that I would like to roll-up to the parent site so the staff member that adds it to their site, doesn't have to request me, or someone else - to add it to the parent site.  Again - we have sharepoint foundation so not sure it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

try the below method.

In SharePoint 2010, it is easy to put list or library data from a sub-site on a top level site in the same site collection, and it doesn’t entail creating any special web parts or breaking any pages off of the site definition!  Here’s how:

1. Open the browser and go to the list or library that you want to
   ultimately display on another site.
2. Click the Library tab in the ribbon, and click the orange Edit
   Library button, to open it up in SharePoint Designer 2010.
   [image]
3. In the Views section on the right, click on the name of ANY view, to
   open it up.  Yes any.  It doesn’t matter which view you pick here.
   Don’t worry, you won’t be modifying this page.
4. Put the cursor inside the content section of the list, so that the
   set of List View Tools tabs are displayed at the top.
5. Click the Web Part tab.  In the Save Web Part section, there are two
   options:
   [image]

**To Site Gallery** – This option is used if you want to have the ability to insert this list onto any site page in the whole site collection.

**To File** – This allows you to save the .WEBPART file on your computer, so that you can import that file onto any page in the site collection.

6. Click To File, and save it to your desktop.  The following question
   pops  up:[image]Do you want this Web Part to always show list data from the current web site? If you select No, the web part will show data from the list at the path ___, relative to the site in which it is used.   It is important to understand what this means.
   Click Yes to save this exact list.  Click No, if you want this web part to be relative.  So for example, if this is a list called Announcements, this web part would be used to display any list with the name Announcements that exists on the site that this web part is imported on.  In this example, it’s a document library called Shared Documents.
7. Click Yes.
8. Close SharePoint Designer.
9. Go to the other site, on which you would like to display this list.
   Click to Add a web part, and click the little Upload button below
   all of the categories of web parts.   Upload the web part and add it
   to the page.

Source:
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=76&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0

Comment: That doesn't work in SharePoint Foundation.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the calendar list view as webpart from source location
2. Upload to webpart gallery of destination
3. Add the web part on a page of destination site

Assuming both are on same site collection.

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers. Edit this one to be more specific. Thank you